# C++ Const Variables calculated during run time?

Tags: c++

In the following code, are the const variable B, C and P calculated once during start-up of the application, or at run time (ie. every time parabolicSine is called)?

Optimising this, wondering if it'll make any difference if I pre-calculated B, C and P. (to avoid division)

Thanks.

```
const double B = 4.0/(float)pi;
const double C = -4.0/((float)pi*(float)pi);
const double P = 0.225;

inline double parabolicSine(double x, bool bHighPrecision = true)
{
    double y = B * x + C * x * fabs(x);

    if(bHighPrecision)
        y = P * (y * fabs(y) - y) + y;   

    return y;
}
```

Comment: They are calculated once even on no optimizations mode.

Comment: Its purely based on compilers. Some compilers compute it at compile time whereas others at run time.

Comment: If you are using C++11, make the variables [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) to require them to computed at compile time.

Comment: @Pradhan I was just about to comment that. Nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` variables are not required to be computed at compile time even when their definition allows it. While most compilers will likely implement it in such trivial cases, the only way to *require* that it be done is to make the variable a [`constexpr`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#cpp11-constexpr). `constexpr` generalizes  the definition of [constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) to variables and functions. In addition, it frees you from having to worry about compiler quirks and instead make it explicit that the variable value should be available at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are calculated once (compile-time), here's the disassembly from GCC:

```
LFE1:
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
__ZL2pi:
    .long   1078523331
    .align 8
__ZL1B:
    .long   -1887771331
    .long   1072980437
    .align 8
__ZL1C:
    .long   256041101
    .long   -1076234516
    .align 8
__ZL1P:
    .long   -858993459
    .long   1070386380
    .align 8
```

Do also note that optimizations don't matter at all in this situation.  It may however, be just pushed on the stack as constants when calling the function (if used once, or so, depends on compiler)

Comment: You forgot to add *"my version of gcc on my computer"*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then please enlighten me with what I wrote wrong here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh we're talking about 1990 compilers or?

Comment: @user9000: Ah, that old chestnut. Like I said, hand-waving. C++ is an abstraction. Teach it as such.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP didn't state he is using C++11, otherwise I highly doubt he would of asked such question here if he were and just went with `constexpr`

Comment: @user9000: You vastly overestimate the number of people who know about `constexpr`. Remember that Visual Studio 2013 is [mostly] C++11 and _doesn't give you a choice_. You don't have to ask for it. You get it. So that's millions of programmers using C++11 possibly without even knowing what C++11 is.

Answer (score 1):

They may not be computed at compile time, but they will be computed no more than once. (A variable only ever gets initialised once.) So there is no chance they will be evaluated on every call to `ParabolicSine`.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence for this? I'm not aware of any such guarantee in this case — the as-if rule would seem to allow these variables to be initialised any number of times.

Comment: @Lightness You are correct. The compiler is free to do unneccessary work at any point (and, I suspect, to inject indefinite delays arbitrarly). In practice it won't, but there is no guarantee. It would be more accurate to say that the virtual machine only performs the computation at most once. (The same is true for `constexpr` too.)

Answer (score 0):

Its compiler based. Consider below example.

```
int n=5; 
int arr[n];// It works fine when compiling with gcc However ERROR : when compiling in Visual Studio.

const int n=5;
int arr[n]; //Compiles successfully in VS
```

Comment: This is not really the point. That VLAs exist in GCC doesn't say anything about the question posed.